# Blueprint for basement design

Tags: basement, framing, design

Does someone have any good resources or guides on how to determine basement framing layout? I bought the house with a half basement finished, but would like to complete the other half and possibly redo this half, so wanted to see if someone has used some good software or websites before.

Comment: Give picture of the whole basement with dimensions plus label the finished part.   You also need to decide if you need a bathroom or a bar/sink.

Comment: Sadly, this is _far_ too broad a question to answer. Are you unsure of what rooms to build in? Are you unsure how to design the framing? If you're just looking for [softwarerecs.se], you should go there.

Comment: Start with a sketch of the basement dimensions. If you're planning a bathroom or even a wet bar, does your drain pipe go into the floor? If not, you'll need pumps to discharge the waste.  Is the basement already dry or does it get damp? What do you want to do with the space?  Sketchup is free and widely used, though not specific for home design it could work.